# Is there a way to find out how many times a class has been instantiated in php?

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently using this method:

```
class Foo {
    private static $num_instances = 0;

    function __construct() {
        self::$num_instances++;
    }
}
```

which seems to work, but I'm wondering if there's a built in way....

Comment: that seemed to me is the only way off my head. A quick search on google and php.net doesn't get me another solution other than this. By the way, you might want to decrement the number when `__destruct()`-ing

Comment: I don't think PHP has any reason to log such info. I'm curious. Do you have a practical need for it at the moment?

Comment: "Need" is a bit strong, but I'm creating one set of objects based on another set, and I want them to maintain their creation order, so I'm using that as a "weight" field. There are plenty of other ways to get around the issue, but this one came to mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be surprised if there is one..
In my opinion it would be an overhead, if it is always counting the amount of created instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/download.php) using the [execution trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace).

Answer (score 0):

You can always check `$GLOBALS` and count the number of class instantiations.

It wouldn't be pretty, and I would prefer to do it with a static property.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it could be to count the instances in the `$GLOBALS` (as suggested by Alix):

```php
function count_instances( $class_name ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $GLOBALS as $key => $global ) {
        if ( 'global' === $key ) continue;
        if ( 'object' === gettype($global) ) {
            if ( $class_name === get_class($global) ) $i++;
        }
    }
    return $i;
}
```

But note that this would not include classes instantiated without being stored in a variable.  For example, it will add the instance of `$var = new className();` to `$GLOBALS` but not simply `new className();` (just the call alone without encapsulation).